# HTML input autoFocus property not rendering with React.renderToStaticMarkup

Tags: html, reactjs

How to include the *autofocus* HTML property into an input using ReactJS component?

I tried it with a React element that contains an input with *autofocus*

```
<input className='EI-input' autoFocus='true' tabIndex='0'
                               name='username' type='text'
                               ref='inputUser' autoComplete='on'
                               placeholder='email' />
```

But when rendering to Static Markup I don't see the autofocus property rendered in the browser (inspecting with devTools in Chrome and FireFox)

```
const jsx = React.renderToStaticMarkup(<InputWithAutoFocus />);
console.log(jsx); // I don't see the autofocus attribute in the input
```

I also tried with just *autoFocus* and *autoFocus='on'* and *autofocus*. None of these seem to work.

autoFocus should work, according the [ReactJS docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not supported due to the interpretations of different browsers:

> "We" decided not to use it because every browser has their unique interpretation of how it should work, literally all browsers do it differently. Overloading it and rendering it to the markup at the same time seems like a bad idea.

see the full thread [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3066)